# How to use the argument of a vimscript function in an inner python function?

Tags: vimscript, vimscript-python

I have the following vimscript: it contains a vimscript function which executes a python code thanks to `python << EOF`:

```
function! Test(myArgument)
python << EOF
def test(myArgument):
    print "My argument " + myArgument

test("foo")
EOF
endfunction
```

How can I use the argument of the vimscript function `a:myArgument` and pass it as argument to my python function (instead of `foo`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `vim` package inside python, you should be able to gain access to vim:

```
function! Test(myArgument)
    python << EOF
import vim

def test(myArgument):
    print "My argument " + myArgument

test(vim.eval('a:myArgument'))
EOF
endfunction
```

You can read about the python integration at `:h python` and about this particular feature at `:h python-eval`.