# passing arguments to pyfile/py3file function

Tags: vimscript-python

I try to do something similar to [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8431/how-to-use-the-argument-of-a-vimscript-function-in-an-inner-python-function).

E.g. I have a python script in a file `/tmp/testme.py` which should do different things depending on what argum
ents are passed to it:

```
import vim

currentline = int(vim.eval('line(".")'))

if vim.argument == "close": # quasi code here
    mylines = [ 'this is the script',
                'and I say good bye!' ]
else:
    mylines = [ 'this is the script',
                'and I say hello!' ]

vim.current.buffer[currentline:currentline] = mylines
```

And I intend to call it from vim with

```
:py3f /tmp/testme.py "close"
```

for the if branch or

```
:py3f /tmp/testme.py
```

for the else branch. Is there a way to pass arguments to scripts called with `pyf` or `py3f`?

The syntax I suggest above fails because `"close"` is understood as second filename and vim tells me off

```
E172: Only one file name allowed
```

or

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "/tmp/testme.py 'close'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:help :pyfile` describes the mechanism to pass arguments as such:

> To pass arguments you need to set `sys.argv[]` explicitly.  Example:

```
:python import sys
:python sys.argv = ["foo", "bar"]
:pyfile myscript.py
```